# C# MapCamera : Singleton<MapCamera> выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, unity3d, singleton

В Unity3d при создании класса "public class MapCamera : Singleton" выдает ошибку:
- The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'MapCamera'. 
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: что интересно если переключаюсь на net 3.5 ошибка пропадает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка говорит вам о том, что такой класс уже существует. Вы уверены, что не добавляли его в проект? Попробуйте поискать в папке по имени.

Если точнее, то в ошибке говориться, что именно в этом пространстве имён класс содержится. Пространство имён можно добавлять, если заключить класс в дополнительные скобки со спец словом, например вот так:

```
namespace Game
{
    public class MapCamera : Singleton
    {

    }
}
```

Подобная конструкция означает, что класс `MapCamera` находится в "пространстве имён Game". Это приведёт к тому, что "видеть" этот класс смогут только классы из того же пространства имен, либо те классы, у которых вверх будет присутствовать строка `using Game;` т.е. им будет дан доступ к конкретному пространству имён.

Классы с одинаковыми именами могут существовать одновременно, если они находятся в разных пространствах имён. Но лучше так не делать, чтобы не запутаться)

Comment: да,создавал public class MapCamera : MonoBehaviour,но я по примеру прямого наследования хочу использовать singleton и в 3.5 то работает...

Comment: @Cmig, чтобы два класса с одинаковым именем существовали - у них должны быть разные пространства имен. Почему вы не переделаете старый класс? зачем вам новый